# find specific vocab and extract row of csv and transform in new csv file

Tags: python, csv, find, transform, extract

I have `30,000` rows list of `csv files` and I want to search through these rows and columns after finding specific words write that row in new csv files.

for example:

```
job ,position , email , adress 

joe  ,validi ,  ceo  ,  joevalidi@yahoo.com
```

I want to know who are `ceo` then extract it and save it in different `csv`files.

Comment: Share sample input and expected output.

Comment: @MayankPorwal I edited it

Comment: Mahdi, this is does not he;p at all what you are asking, however worth to show the minimal code and the dataset which you are working on! there is nothing relevant from the output you have shown.

Answer (score 1):

say this is your input file `test.txt` located at `/Users/redwing/temp/`

```
/Users/cat/meow/meoew
/Users/cat/meow/meoew2
/Users/dog/bow/wow
```

then this script would output a file containing only the lines that contain `cat`.

```
in_fname = '/Users/redwing/temp/test.txt'
out_fname = '/Users/redwing/temp/test_output.txt'

f_out = open(out_fname, 'w+')
f_in = open(in_fname, 'r')
for content in f_in:
    if 'cat' in content:
        f_out.write(content)
f_in.close()
f_out.close()
```

nice thing about this solution is that all of the file is never read into memory, so it does not matter if you filter 3000 or 30 million rows.

PS. Submitted my response before your edit. Obviously you need just to replace `cat` with a `ceo` )

Comment: I think this is not an appropriate thing to do and discuss in this website. if people stumble across your question and find it useful they upvote it. Not to mention that it would be nice if you accepted mine or Mayank's response )

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: use `re` module

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'ceo')
ceo_list = []

with open('managers.csv', 'r') as f:  ## where managers.csv is the file you shared above
    for i in f:
        if pattern.search(i):
            ceo_list.append(i.split(',')[0].strip())
```

Now, you have all `ceo`'s stored in the list `ceo_list`. Just write it into a separate file:

```
with open('ceo.csv', 'w') as f:
    for item in ceo_list:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Let me know if this helps.